# Can AWS Lambda write CSV to response?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, amazon-web-services, lambda

like the question says, I would like to know if it is possible to return the response request of a lambda function in CSV format. I already know that is possible to write JSON objects as such, but for my current project, CSV format is necessary. I have only seen discussion of writing CSV files to S3, but that is what we need for this project.

This is an example of what I would like to have displayed in a response:

> year,month,day,hour
>
> 2017,10,11,00
>
> 2017,10,11,01
>
> 2017,10,11,02
>
> 2017,10,11,03
>
> 2017,10,11,04
>
> 2017,10,11,05
>
> 2017,10,11,06
>
> 2017,10,11,07
>
> 2017,10,11,08
>
> 2017,10,11,09

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see why you can't. It's just the same as how you do it with flask or Django -- you set the content type as `text/csv` and the CSV string as the body.

Comment: Hi dashmug, could you please send me a code snippet demonstrating this if it is possible? Would I be able to tune it on demand if I needed to switch between `text/csv` and `application/json`? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I think I gave you enough pointers to start with. Write some code and include it in your question. We can then help you out if it doesn't work. Just start by sending the CSV string as a response.

Comment: basically what we are asking is: show us your code, show us your input, show us your output, and show us your expected output.... then ask a question, and I am pretty sure someone will try to answer what you are asking.